# Simple Income Tax Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

My very first computer program, a very simple income tax calculator. What can I do to get the same outcome with better efficiency?

```
# 2021 income tax calculator
print ('What\'s your yearly income after you deduct all expenses?')
myincome = int(input())
base = (myincome*.1)
e = (max(myincome-9950,0)*.02)
ex = (max(myincome-40525,0)*.1)
ext = (max(myincome-86376,0)*.02)
extr = (max(myincome-164926,0)*.08)
extra = (max(myincome-209426,0)*.03)
extras = (max(myincome-523601,0)*.02)
tax = base + e + ex + ext + extr + extra + extras
print ('You\'re gonna get screwed about~$',str(tax) + ' dollars in Federal income tax')
print ()
while True:

    print ('Try Different Income:')
    myincome = int(input())
    base = (myincome*.1)
    e = (max(myincome-9950,0)*.02)
    ex = (max(myincome-40525,0)*.1)
    ext = (max(myincome-86376,0)*.02)
    extr = (max(myincome-164926,0)*.08)
    extra = (max(myincome-209426,0)*.03)
    extras = (max(myincome-523601,0)*.02)
    tax = base + e + ex + ext + extr + extra + extras
    print ('You\'re gonna get screwed about~$',str(tax) + ' dollars in Federal income tax')
    print ()
    continue
```

Comment: Hi @JJZ - what if someone enters a negative value for income?   Or zero?  And where's the formula from (maybe add where the calcuation is from - since you mention the YR the calc is for)..  AND it's for US Federal Taxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should split your code into reusable functions instead of manually rewriting / copying code.
2. You should put your code into a `main()` function and wrap the call to it in a `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).
3. Variable names like `e, ex, ext, ...` aren't descriptive.
4. You should include error handling for user input.
5. You don't need seperate variables for every single tax bracket, rather you want a list of all tax brackets to iterate over.
6. Depending on the income, you shouldn't always need to calculate all tax brackets. Once a bracket doesn't apply to the income, the subsequent brackets won't apply either.
7. There should not be a space in `print (...)`
8. There should be spaces around operators and commas in `e = (max(myincome-9950,0)*.02)` -> `e = (max(myincome - 9950, 0) * .02)`
9. If applicable, use your IDEs auto-formatting feature (e.g. `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `L` in PyCharm) to automatically avoid the aforementioned formatting issues.
10. f-Strings make printing text including variables really convenient and handle string conversion for you.
11. Type annotations are generally a good idea. They're beneficial to readability and error-checking.

---

**Suggested code**

```
TAX_BRACKETS = [
    (0, 0.1),
    (9950, 0.02),
    (40525, 0.1),
    (86376, 0.02),
    (164926, 0.08),
    (209426, 0.03),
    (523601, 0.02)
]


def get_income(prompt: str = "", force_positive: bool = False) -> int:
    try:
        income = int(input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
        print("Could not convert income to integer, please try again.")
        return get_income(prompt=prompt, force_positive=force_positive)

    if force_positive and income < 0:
        print("Income must not be negative, please try again.")
        return get_income(prompt=prompt, force_positive=force_positive)

    return income


def calculate_income_tax(income: float) -> float:
    tax = 0

    for bracket, rate in TAX_BRACKETS:
        if bracket > income:
            break

        tax += (income - bracket) * rate

    return tax


def print_tax(tax: float) -> None:
    print(f"You're gonna get screwed about~${tax} dollars in Federal income tax\n")


def main():
    income = get_income(prompt="What's your yearly income after you deduct all expenses?\n")
    federal_income_tax = calculate_income_tax(income)
    print_tax(federal_income_tax)

    while True:
        income = get_income(prompt="Try different income:\n")
        federal_income_tax = calculate_income_tax(income)
        print_tax(federal_income_tax)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This code is repeating 2 times

```
myincome = int(input())
base = (myincome*.1)
e = (max(myincome-9950,0)*.02)
ex = (max(myincome-40525,0)*.1)
ext = (max(myincome-86376,0)*.02)
extr = (max(myincome-164926,0)*.08)
extra = (max(myincome-209426,0)*.03)
extras = (max(myincome-523601,0)*.02)
tax = base + e + ex + ext + extr + extra + extras
print ('You\'re gonna get screwed about~$',str(tax) + ' dollars in Federal income tax')
print ()
```

Instead of repeating 2 times, create a function named `getIncome`, call it after `print ('What\'s your yearly income after you deduct all expenses?')` and `print ('Try Different Income:')`

2. Why calling `print()` with no string, if you want to add a EOL, add `+'\n'` while calling the print statement before it.
3. Your code is looking a bit dirty, use a code style guideline, like [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)